# Spring boot CRUD application - Bean not found error

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I am developing a simple CRUD application with spring-boot.

I have most of the project completed, although I get this error when I try to run the project.

> Description:
>
> Field userDBOP in com.application.crud.GreetingController required a
>   bean of type 'com.application.crud.myoperation.JdbcUserDAO' that could
>   not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'com.application.crud.myoperation.JdbcUserDAO' in your configuration.

In IntelliJ when I hover over the line that causes the error, the following message shows up

> "Could not autowire. No beans of 'JdbcUserDAO' type found.

Even though I have in my 'Beans.xml' file (located below the 'src' directory:

```
<bean id="customerDAO" class="com.application.crud.myoperation.JdbcUserDAO">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with **configuring a Spring Boot Application with an existing Spring Context**. There is a section in the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-importing-xml-configuration) about this.

By default, you need to specify the location of your application context using the `@ImportResource` annotation. An example would be:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("applicationContext.xml")
public class ExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(ExampleApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Note** that if the file is located elsewhere in the classpath, then you need to reference it properly for spring to pick it up (e.g `@ImportResource({"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"})` )

Comment: I am trying this but I keep getting the error "resource : beans.xml cannot be opened because it doesn't exist.... I have tried moving this file into the same directory as the Application class, I have also tried putting a full path to the file but no luck.. any suggestion?

Comment: @smith_05_bird I don't know your file structure, but I think I can give you an approach. Using maven convention, suppose the file is located in `source/main/java/com/app/beans.xml`, then the annotation should be `@ImportResource({"classpath:com/app/beans.xml})` AND the file needs to exist on your build output (which might mean a project clean to get it there OR put it in source/main/resources subfolder instead of source/main/java folder)

Comment: Ok I've moved it to the resources directory and now it works. thanks

Comment: just add the below tag in pom.xml inside build tag and it will work.

<resources>
   <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
   </resource>
  </resources>